# Checking a database for a value, while creating a foreach loop checkbox

Tags: php

I am currently trying to achieve an assignable "bin" system for managing parts within a small warehouse. I am trying to achieve the following;

There is availability of 100 bins I want to list in a select drop-down, and I want to list all 100 - as well  as wanting to show already assigned bins - but have them disabled by utilising a select box with options The list of already assigned bins has to be achieved by first checking the database, but this is where i am having issues.

I have nearly got there, but feel like i'm probably approaching the wrong way, and can't seem to get my head around the checking against the database once within the loop.

I have tried the below code to try and achieve this; but the issue i am having is checking against the database for the value to disable the selectables. $partbin is assigned earlier in the code.

```
    <select name="part_bin">    
<option value="0">No Bin</option>
<?php

// Assign Part Bin


// Start 1-100
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)    {


// First Select from database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE part_bin != NULL OR part_bin != 0";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$nlcheck = $result->fetch_assoc();
$nlbin = $nlcheck["part_bin"];
 // Start Option loop

?>


<option value="<?php echo $i;?>"<?php if($partbin == $i) { echo " selected"; } ?><?php if ($nlbin == $i) { echo " disabled"; }?>>Part Bin <?php echo $i;?></option>


<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

Part bins already assigned within the parts table, should be visible but not selectable via being disabled in the dropdown.

Comment: how do you know that a bin is already assigned ?

Comment: A part should have a status of part_bin= 0(no bin) if not assigned or would have a value matching the bin number in the same field, if selected, the idea here was to check against the table and see if the part has already been assigned to any bin or not - if it has, make the option un-selectable on the drop-down.

Comment: I have noticed today, that the code is working to the point, that it's checking against the first line of the table, and disabling that box, so my question really is - how do i get this to check against all rows while within a loop?